# Badge Request: "Philanthropist" for Receiving 100 Upvotes on Community Wiki Answers

Tags: feature-request, badges, community-wiki, badge-request

I'd think it would be a silver badge. Receive a net 100 upvotes on your answers to questions flagged as Community Wiki.

Answer (score 6):

You can already receive many of the current badges for CW answers (Nice Answer, Good Answer, Great Answer, etc.). Why do you need another one?

Comment: Good point. However, some users lose sight of this. Specifically encouraging users to participate in community wiki questions benefits the community as a whole.

Comment: @Bob: I don't see how getting people to participate in CW questions is beneficial, or needed for that matter. Many questions marked as CW were made that way because they are very subjective and open-ended (i.e. they are designed more for fun, discussion, taking opinion polls, etc.). These sorts of questions *already* get huge numbers of contributions and attention.

Answer (score 5):

So if you provide a mediocre CW answer, and I edit it and improve it slightly, and someone else adds some stuff, and then I come back and fix the formatting, and then another guy shows up and corrects all the factual errors, and folks up-vote this now-great answer...

...then *you* should get another badge? How does this encourage the rest of us to participate...?

For a concrete example of what [gnovice is getting at](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41638/badge-request-philanthropist-for-receiving-100-upvotes-on-community-wiki-answe/41640#41640), take a look at [my Super User profile](https://superuser.com/users/1243/shog9)... 6 silver badges for CW answers that are not only effectively worthless, but which *I didn't even write*. This "Philanthropist" idea would grant me yet another badge for doing nothing.

Comment: But that's what happens with existing badges like "good answer"/"great answer"/etc, right?

Comment: ...which brings us back to gnovice's question: "Why do you need another one"? IMHO, folks who participate in CW answers *now* are doing so because they care about the subject; adding more gee-gaws does nothing useful for this.

Answer (score 3):

I disagree. People already get "good answer"/"great answer"/etc badges in CW posts. It would be one more badge for essentially the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

Meh.

Most of the crap appears under CW (seemingly due to a mistaken impression that makes it OK), and it is possible that most of the CW material is crap (though I wouldn't swear to that).

We certainly don't need another reason for people to post *more* of it.

And you can't have any pudding if you don eat your meat.

And stay off my lawn.

Comment: I remember when we had to trudge uphill and barefoot a mile through the snow to get answers to our programming questions!

Comment: @gnovice: You forgot to mention that we had to find the answers in books read by candlelight at the library which was uphill both ways and only open on Tuesdays. ::someone just old enough to have done research before the internet took over::